# Pandas how to preserve all values in dataframe into a csv?

Tags: python, html, pandas, csv

I want to convert the html to csv using pandas functions
This is a part of what I read in the dataframe df

```
0                                                  1
0          sequence                                                  2
1           trainNo                                               K805
2       trainNumber                                               K805
3     departStation                                                 鹰潭
4   departStationPy                                            yingtan
5     arriveStation                                                 南昌
6   arriveStationPy                                           nanchang
7        departDate                                         2020-05-24
8        departTime                                              03:55
9        arriveDate                                         2020-05-24
10       arriveTime                                              05:44
11   isStartStation                                              False
12     isEndStation                                              False
13          runTime                                            1小时49分钟
14      preSaleTime                                                NaN
15         takeDays                                                  0
16       isBookable                                               True
17         seatList  seatNamepriceorderPriceinventoryisBookablebutt...
18     curSeatIndex                                                  0
  seatName  price  orderPrice  inventory  isBookable  buttonDisplayName  buttonType
0       硬座   23.5        23.5         99        True                NaN           0
1       硬卧   69.5        69.5         99        True                NaN           0
2       软卧  104.5       104.5          4        True                NaN           0
                        0           1
0              departDate  2020-05-23
1       departStationList         NaN
2          endStationList         NaN
3  departStationFilterMap         NaN
4     endStationFilterMap         NaN
5          departCityName          上海
6          arriveCityName          南昌
7              gtMinPrice         NaN
```

My code is like this

```
for i, df in enumerate(pd.read_html(html,encoding='utf-8')):
    df.to_csv(".\other.csv",index=True,encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

To preserve the characters in csv, I need to use utf-8-sig encoding. But I don't know how to write the format symbol %

```
,0,1
0,departDate,2020-05-23
1,departStationList,
2,endStationList,
3,departStationFilterMap,
4,endStationFilterMap,
5,departCityName,上海
6,arriveCityName,南昌
7,gtMinPrice,
```

This is what I got in csv file, only the last part is preserved.
The dataframe is correct, while the csv need correction. Can you show me how to make the correct output?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado OK. I will update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you're saving each dataframe to the same file, so each is getting overwritten until the last one.
- note the addition of the f-string to change the save file name e.g. `f".\other_{i}.csv"`
- each dataframe is a different shape, so they won't all fit together properly

### To CSV

```py
for i, df in enumerate(pd.read_html(html,encoding='utf-8')):
    df.to_csv(f".\other_{i}.csv", index=True, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

### To Excel

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', mode='w') as writer:
    for i, df in enumerate(pd.read_html(html,encoding='utf-8')):
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'Sheet{i}', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```